# Change backgroundPosition with onmouseover events

Tags: javascript, css, html

I need a bit of help. I've run into an issue of trying to invoke a change in backgroundPosition of a block element when one link from a list is - you guessed it - moused over. Here's the kicker: It needs to be viable in an external .js file (inline JS looks really messy and unprofessional imho). All of the solutions I've seen so far are either too simple (CSS-only solutions won't work, due to separated elements) or use things I'm not comfortable with yet (that means no jQuery, thanks).

What I would like is something along the lines of an if-else statement (if at all possible. If not, the next closest thing will do), which would look/perform something like:

```
var block = document.getElementById('block');
if (onmouseover *link1*) {
    block.style.backgroundPosition='-200px 0px';
} else if (onmouseover *link2*) {
    block.style.backgroundPosition='-400px 0px';
} else if (onmouseover *link3*) {
    block.style.backgroundPosition='0px -200px';
}
```

If any other sections of code are needed, I'll provide them if possible. Thanks in advance!

EDIT: To be clear, I'm not asking for the whole JS program (I'm not THAT dumb...), just how I would go about getting the if statement to recognize that one element has been moused-over and modify another correspondingly, as all my attempts so far have been met with failure.

Comment: You should make it work with CSS. Using JavaScript simply for stylistic changes is messy and unprofessional.

Comment: can you post your code to jsfiddle or jsbin

Comment: @MichaelIrigoyen is right, doing it in javascript may not work in some browser.

Comment: use jquery :P or better yet, use css hover

Comment: @user2108886 Please post a simplified snippet of the HTML too.

Comment: @Michael using CSS-only won't work, I'm trying to manipulate one element from another, which is - afaik - impossible.

Comment: @abdul http://jsbin.com/icofis/1/ There's no JS because the stuff I have right now is almost entirely pseudo-code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are making something quite simple into something way too complicated.

is this what you are trying to get? No need for javascript at all.

Check out the JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/ionko22/fjTUA/

Basic HTML

```
<a id="hover-me1">Link 1</a>
<a id="hover-me2">Link 2</a>
<a id="hover-me3">Link 3</a>

<div id="change-my-background"></div>
```

And Basic CSS

```
#hover-me1:hover ~ #change-my-background{
    background:#aa3233 url(http://i.imgur.com/DMv02cc.jpg) repeat-x -200px -200px;
}

#hover-me2:hover ~ #change-my-background{
    background:#aa3233 url(http://i.imgur.com/DMv02cc.jpg) repeat-x -400px -200px;
}

#hover-me3:hover ~ #change-my-background{
    background:#aa3233 url(http://i.imgur.com/DMv02cc.jpg) repeat-x -600px -200px;
}

#change-my-background {
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
}
```

Comment: I actually had no idea this was even possible with just CSS. Thanks!